# Merge user info email/phone number authentication, Firebase firestore with swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Create a user with Username, email, and password. Then force the user to complete phone number verification before the account is created.

I am designing an app where we would like to make the user sign up by creating a username, password, supply their email address, and then complete phone number verification.

[image]

This picture represents the desired flow we would like our user to complete to register their account.

here are our View Controller files:

This is the code for the "Create Account" view, it creates a user in Firebase using email

```
import UIKit
class CreateAccountVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordTextfield: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var createAccountLbl: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var createAccountTextView: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var signupBtn: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide), name:UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        signupBtn.clipsToBounds = true
        signupBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        signupBtn.addButtonGradient(didType: true)
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification){

        let userInfo = notification.userInfo!
        var keyboardFrame:CGRect = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        keyboardFrame = self.view.convert(keyboardFrame, from: nil)
        var contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = self.scrollView.contentInset
        contentInset.bottom = keyboardFrame.size.height
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    }

    @objc func keyboardWillHide(notification:NSNotification){
        let contentInset:UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        scrollView.contentInset = contentInset
    }
    @IBAction func alreadyHaveAccountBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
//        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
//        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "TypePhoneNumberVC", sender: self)
    }
    @IBAction func signupBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        let username = usernameTextfield.text
        let email = emailTextfield.text
        let password = passwordTextfield.text
        signupBtn.isHidden = true
        AuthorizationService.instance.registerUser(username: username!, email: email!, password: password!) { (success, err) in
            if success{
                AuthorizationService.instance.loginUser(withEmail: email!, andPassword: password!) { (success, err) in
                    if err != nil{
                        return
                    }
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "EnterNumberSegue", sender: self)
                    print("Sign-up successful")
                }
            }else{
                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: err?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                self.signupBtn.isHidden = false
            }

        }
    }
    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

These next two demonstrate the implementation of the Phone number verification

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth


class EnterPhoneNumberVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var backButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberUITextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var getCodeButton: UIButton!

    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        phoneNumberUITextField.delegate = self
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handle))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light

    }
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        getCodeButton.clipsToBounds = true
        getCodeButton.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        getCodeButton.addButtonGradient(didType: true)
    }
    @objc func handle(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func getCodeButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        guard let phoneNumber = phoneNumberUITextField.text else {return}

        PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print(verificationID)
                guard let verifyID = verificationID else {return}
                self.userDefaults.set(verifyID, forKey:"verificationID")
                self.userDefaults.synchronize()
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "GetCodeSegue", sender: self)
            } else {
                print("unable to confirm the users phone number", error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth

class PhoneNumberVerificationVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var verifyBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var resendCodeBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var otpCode: UITextField!

    var verificationID: String?
    let userDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handle))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        verifyBtn.clipsToBounds = true
        verifyBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        verifyBtn.addButtonGradient(didType: true)
    }
    @objc func handle(tap: UITapGestureRecognizer){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func verifyBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let optCode = otpCode.text else {return}
        guard let verificationID = userDefaults.string(forKey: "verificationID") else {return}
        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(withVerificationID: verificationID, verificationCode: optCode)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (success, error) in
            if error == nil {
                print(success)
                 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "VerifiedSegue", sender: self)
                print("The user has successfully logged In and is verified!")
            } else {
                print("Error: Phone number and One time password does not match")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you clarify what your question is? in which part you are exactly stuck? Have a look at [1] so that you can refine more your question.  [1] https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We do not understand how to update the user profile information once they verify their phone number

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895856/how-to-merge-emailandpasswordauth-with-phoneauth-in-firebase) has solved a similar problem of mine in the past.